# Windows. Folder which ends with dot

Tags: windows, directory

Is it possible create folder that ends with dot in Windows? When folder starts with dot there is no problem, but not if ends. Am I not alone with this?

Comment: `md \\?\C:\Path\To\Folder.`

Comment: @PetSerAl Why don't you post that as an answer. It works.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you could create folder that ends with a period. You can try it yourself by showing hidden extensions on windows.